# Uninitialized Constant, request Parameters ???? Lost with errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uninitialized-constant

I am following this tutorial on rails (http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/merchant.html) and running into an error I have been getting for a while now. The error message that I am getting is below stating

```
uninitialized constant OrderItem::ProductId
```

and my code below. It highlights the line starting with @order_item as well.

```
# POST /order_items.json
  def create
    @order_item = OrderItem.new(product_id: params[:product_id], order_id: @order_id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order_item.save
```

**And it tells me this as well.**

Request Parameters:

```
{"authenticity_token"=>"yCeOPJCrLoK2jYBXnjPVra8jtPjOa98UCXXRA51ySxY=",
 "product_id"=>"1"}
```

Does anyone have a clue as to what is going on here? A couple other people checked it out and couldn't help me so I'm hoping someone could lead me in the right direction here.

Comment: Show your model ` OrderItem` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :order
 belongs_to :order_id
 belongs_to :product_id
end

Comment: you dont need belongs_to :order_id and  belongs_to :product_id,also this not the correct way of creating belongs_to associations, just add   belongs_to :order and belongs_to :product

Comment: You better look into these Guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association

Comment: my catch was right.. ;)